BrowserModuleAnimations and Angular Material conflicting with BrowserModule dependancy
core.mjs:6531 ERROR Error: NG05100: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.

I am creating an application which is in Angular 17. Here they have removed app-module and app-routing and they made all the components to act as standalone and import necessary modules in each component.
I wanted to use mat-accordion which is from angular/material. This package imports BrowserModule by default and since its Angular 17 - the application starts from main.ts file and its using bootstrapApplication from '@angular/platform-browser' and this module also have BrowserModule which is like conflicting. I tried many solutions looking into stackoverflow but none of the solutions are working. Any expertise who can help me ?

I found the answer by importing BrowserAnimationsModule in main.ts file referenced in this link.
Example here
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
 bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [
      provideRouter(routes, withHashLocation()),
      importProvidersFrom(BrowserAnimationsModule),
  ],
 })

